# ¿Como se hace este pequeño programa?

Tags: java, matrices

> Es un ejercicio que no consigo resolver, además que mis conocimientos sobre matrices, aún es nula y no sé por donde empezar.

```
public class ControlMatriz {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "null" })
    public void cien1NumNatural(int x, int supx)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<supx;j++){
                    int[][] matrizM = null;
                    System.out.println(matrizM[i][j]);
                    if (matrizM[i][j] % 2==0)
                        System.out.println(matrizM[i][j]*5);
                    }
                 }
              }
    }
```

Comment: amigo cerraran tu tema si no proporcionas algun codigo de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Simplemente mejora tus conocimientos , el que te lo hagan no te favorecerá. El esforzarte a hacerlo y sacrificarte es lo que logrará que para la siguiente ya lo sepas hacer.

Comment: vale, gracias @CodeNoob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primero:** Calcular ¿cuántos? y ¿cuales? serán las bases.

```
int total = num_introducido / 2;    // calcula cuantas pares hay
int[] bases = new int[total];       // crea el arreglo
for(int i = 1; i <= total; i ++)
    bases[i-1] = i * 2;               // carga el arreglo
```

**Segundo:**  Calcular las potencias.

```
int[][] potencias = new int[total][5];

for(int i = 0; i < total; i++){ 
      potencias[i][0] = bases[i];
      potencias[i][1] = (int) Math.pow(bases[i], 2);
      potencias[i][2] = (int) Math.pow(bases[i], 3);
      potencias[i][3] = (int) Math.pow(bases[i], 4);
      potencias[i][4] = (int) Math.pow(bases[i], 5);
}
```

**Tecero:** Imprimes la información.

```
for(int i = 0; i < total; i++){

      System.out.print(potencias[i][0] + " - ");
      System.out.print(potencias[i][1] + " - ");
      System.out.print(potencias[i][2] + " - ");
      System.out.print(potencias[i][3] + " - ");
      System.out.println(potencias[i][4]);

}
```

Aunque no es necesario del todo el arreglo bases, en el segundo ciclo, podrías sustituirlo por:

`((i + 1) * 2)`